# Angular - Every console error is emitted from instrumentConsole.js

Tags: angular, console.log

I am working on a fairly big Angular 11 project, and I have been getting every single one of my console errors from `instrumentConsole.js`.

It would be best if I could receive the error from the file that generated it, so I would like to revert it back.

I am using Angular v11.2.14, with NPM v9.1.3, Node at v16.18.1 and Chrome in version 115.0.5790.171, 64 bits.

Thank you so much.

[image: Screenshot from my dev tools console. which shows an error using instrumentConsole as the source]

Comment: Does your project use Sentry?

Comment: Do you use `addEventListener("error"` ?

Comment: @JSONDerulo it does not

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler no, I don't

Comment: where does that intrumentConsole.js file come from ? Hover on the file name to see its path.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler it came from an extension I had recently installed named Bird Eats Bug. For some reason I thought this was a screen recording extension, which would actually be useful.
Thank you, this tip really helped me to trace it back.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Sentry or similar crash reporting tool

Comment: Hello. I was actually using one and didn't notice it, as I mentioned in my comment above. It was the Bird Eats Bug extension. Thank you very much!